# Trying to read blobs from azure container with prefix using python, but facing error "'ItemPaged' object has no attribute 'objects'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

Below is my code,

```
def s3Select(path, asJson = True):
    #cfg = current_app.config
    #data = []
    #s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    #my_bucket = s3.Bucket(cfg["S3_BUCKET"])
    connection_string=''
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("sourcedata")
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs("sourcemetadata")
    #files = list(my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path))
    files = list(blob_list.objects.filter(Prefix=path))
    for i in range(0,len(files)):
        obj = s3.Object(blob_list.name, files[i].key)
        if asJson:
            tmp_data = json.loads(obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
            data.append(tmp_data)
        else:
            data.append(obj)
```

Error : 'ItemPaged' object has no attribute 'objects'

New to azure development in python, please do guide!

Answer (score 0):

As per the SDK documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#list-blobs-name-starts-with-none--include-none----kwargs-), list_blobs method returns a collection of [`BlobProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobproperties?view=azure-python) and that does not have a Prefix property. This is why you're getting this error.

If your intention is to get a list of blobs names of which start with certain characters, you can actually do a server-side filtering. Just pass the prefix as `name_starts_with` parameter value and storage service will only return the matching blobs.

Comment: files = container_client.list_blobs("sourcemetadata","name_starts_with=ABC") Error: include must be type [ListBlobsIncludeItem].